# D3: can create a subset of elements, but not update them

Tags: d3.js, selection

I have a dataset, one element of which is another dataset (let's call it "dataset2"), of a variable length.

I create a complex plot:

```
var group = svg.selectAll('g').data(dataset)
var groupEnter = group.enter().append('g')

/* Add new elements */  
groupEnter.append('line')  
    ...  
groupEnter.append('polygon')  
    ...  
groupEnter.append('text')  
    ...  

/* Update elements */
group.select('line')  
    ...  
group.select('polygon')  
    ...  
group.select('text')  
    ...
```

So far so good.

Now, I want to add polygons representing "dataset2":

```
var subGroup = group.selectAll('.someClass').data(function(d) { return d['dataset2'] })

var subGroupEnter = subGroup.enter().append('polygon')
    .attr('class', 'someClass')
    ...
```

This seems to work; polygons are created.

However, I can't update them:

```
subGroup.selectAll('.someClass')
    ...
```

This has no effect.

If I ran

```
subGroup.selectAll('.someClass')
    .attr('...', function(d) { console.log(d); return ... })
```

there is no output.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

That's because you're not actually adding `someClass` to the subgroup (at least in the fragments you show)

Maybe

```
var subGroupEnter = subGroup.enter().append('polygon').classed('someClass', true)
```

Or something similar (hard to be more specific with just the fragments above)

Comment: You're right: I specify class in ".attr('class', 'someClass')" but don't mention it in the code above. I fixed the question.